# Probability after exactly k steps

Tags: probability

Here is lottery machine, if the current no. on the screen is "1" then probability of getting "2" is "a" and probability of getting "3" is "b" and probability of getting "1" is "c", after each step.
where "a"+"b"+"c"=1.
similarly, 
if the current no. on the screen is "2" then probability of getting "1" is "d" and probability of getting "3" is "e" and probability of getting "2" is "f".
where "d"+"e"+"f"=1.
and,
if the current no. on the screen is "3" then probability of getting "1" is "g" and probability of getting "2" is "h" and probability of getting "3" is "i".
where "g"+"h"+"i"=1.

then what is probability of getting "1" after exactly k steps, if current no. on screen is:
a)"1",
b)"2",
c)"3".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The process can be described as a Markov Chain with transition matrix $$\mathbf{P}=\pmatrix{c&a&b\\d&f&e\\g&h&i}$$ Now for 1) $$P(X_k=1|X_0=1)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}p_{1j}^n\cdot p_{j1}^{k-n}$$ by the Chapman-Kolmogorov equations. Similarly for 2) and 3). Alternatively you can use that $$\mathbf{P}^{(k)}=\mathbf{P}^k$$ However I do not think that it is easy to make these calculations in such a general setting.